# how to Enable RTCView to Enable Audio and Video Calls

Tags: javascript, react-native, webrtc

New to this.

I recently integrated WebRTC into a react native expo mobile application.
I have this source code, but I want to integrate 2 extra features.

1.) Enable share functionality between apps.

2.) Enable Audio and video calls between apps so Android users can use this

My code is looking thus

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { Button, SafeAreaView, View } from "react-native";
    import { mediaDevices, RTCView } from "react-native-webrtc";
    
    const App = () => {
      const [stream, setStream] = useState(null);
      const start = async () => {
        if (!stream) {
          let s;
          try {
            s = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
            setStream(s);
          } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
          }
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <SafeAreaView>
            {stream && <RTCView style={{height: 550, width: '100%'}} zOrder={20} objectFit={"cover"} mirror={true} streamURL={stream.toURL()} />}
            <View>
              <Button title="Start" onPress={start} />
            </View>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </>
      );
    };

export default App;
```

And my app.json is looking like this

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      "@config-plugins/react-native-webrtc"
    ],
    "name": "webrtcomen",
    "slug": "webrtcomen",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bitcode": false
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
        "android.permission.BLUETOOTH",
        "android.permission.CAMERA",
        "android.permission.INTERNET",
        "android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS",
        "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",
        "android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW",
        "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
      ],
      "package": "com.iwuagwuemmy.webrtcomen"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there something I need to also add, I am new to this.